# Condition on all eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am going to help *Mathematica* to satisfy the condition:

> If all elements of a matrix's eigenvalues are different from zero, then print "ok"

For `matrix={{1, 1}, {2, 2}}`:

```
If[Eigenvalues[matrix] != 0, Print@"OK"]
```

must print OK.

and for `matrix={{1, 0}, {2, 0}}` its result is nothing.

How can show **All elements** of a list in a condition?

Comment: Your given `matrix={{1, 0}, {2, 0}}` has eigenvalues `{1, 0}` and so this command should print nothing; your statement that "it must print OK" disagrees with your requirement of printing "OK" only when all eigenvalues are nonzero.

Comment: you are right. I corrected it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
If[Det[matrix] != 0, Print["ok"]]
```

The reason why this works is that `Det[matrix]` is the product of all of the eigenvalues of `matrix`. If and only if any of the eigenvalues is zero, then the determinant is zero. There is no need to calculate the eigenvalues here.

A paranoid version would be

```
If[! PossibleZeroQ[Det[matrix]], Print["ok"]]
```

which is a bit more careful in checking whether the determinant is really zero.

For large matrices you may need to calculate the determinant numerically if speed is an issue: `Det[N[matrix]]` instead of `Det[matrix]`.

---

If you think I'm not addressing your question, please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
 matrix = {{1, 0}, {2, 0}};
 If[MemberQ[Eigenvalues[matrix], 0], , Print["Ok"]]
```